# Changing part of method body with javassist

Tags: java, javassist

Let me first explain my goal ... I need to change **part** of a method body, I mean, inside the method I have several calls but just one of these calls need to be change to use two parameters instead of just 1. Since I wanna keep all the rest the same inside the method I thought on get the method body, change thru regexp this specific call I wanna change and set it back again.

Suppose that is good way to do that ... how can I get the method body?

Any suggestion will be really appreciated

Thanks

Raphael Moita

Comment: just out of curiosity, what is the condition that triggers these two different versions? To me this sounds like something that could be solved must more elegantly with classic OO concepts such as (ad-hoc) polymorphism

Comment: are you tied to javassist? I'm not clear on precisely what you are trying to achieve functionally, but swapping a method call for a two method variant should be relatively straightforward using ASM  (assuming the value for the second parameter is easily available)

Comment: JustDanyul, this specific call I wanna include a 2nd parameter belongs to a infrastructure API that every system uses and that API is also responsible for start/load those systems. Instead of ask (even if I could do that) all the team to change their codes to call this 2 parameter method, I wanna to do that change at time to start/load their systems.

Comment: henry, no I`m really not tied to javassist. I`ll take a look on ASM too. Any specific page to suggest me? Thanks

Comment: I took a brief look at ASM as henry suggested and I decide to keep my mind on Javassist (atleast for me it's no so straightforward  as he said :)) So, let me make another question, actually it's a refrased question: Do you guys know if it's possible to know if a method calls other specific method on its body?

Comment: @RaphaelMoita Yes, take a look at the JVM Bytecode specification.

Answer (score 3):

I've had to do some modifications in static initializer of a class today and it's possible to do with **Javaasist**. It's quite hard though. You need to have at least some knowledge about java byte code generation/processing (you no longer have sources after compilation).

You'll probably find this Wikipedia page useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings. It contains list of all Java byte code instructions, what parameters they take and what they do on the stack.

Here's the code (**Groovy**, but should be very easy to translate to Java). What it does is that it goes trough byte code of static class initializer and removes all assignments instructions to static `oldFieldName` that was previously renamed in bytecode. Hope you find it useful.

```
def oldFieldName = "removedField"
def cp = ClassPool.getDefault()
//Create new class out of name and bytes
cp.insertClassPath(new ByteArrayClassPath(name, bytes))

def initializer = cc.classInitializer;                                                    
def mi = initializer.getMethodInfo();                                                     
def ca = mi.getCodeAttribute();                                                           

def ci = ca.iterator()                                                                    
//Let's check all bytecode operations in static initializer                               
while (ci.hasNext()) {                                                                    
    def index = ci.next()                                                                 
    int op = ci.byteAt(index)                                                             
    //PUTSTATIC is a bytecode instruction to assign value from stack to static variable   
    if (op == Opcode.PUTSTATIC) {                                                         
        //Address of target variable is calculated like this                              
        def targetFieldAddr = (ci.byteAt(index + 1) << 8) + ci.byteAt(index + 2)          
        def fieldrefName = mi.getConstPool().getFieldrefName(targetFieldAddr)             
        if (fieldrefName == oldFieldName) {                                               
            //Ok, so it's an assignment to renamed variable                               
            //Let's change assignemt to pop from stack (POP2 -> pop long/double value)           
            //We have to remove it or stack won't be valid                                   
            ci.writeByte((byte) Opcode.POP2, index);                                      
            //PUTSTATIC takes 2 arguments so we have to cleare them out          
            //or they will be used as bytecode instructions and probably invalidate class
            ci.writeByte((byte) Opcode.NOP, index + 1);                                   
            ci.writeByte((byte) Opcode.NOP, index + 2);                                   
    }                                                                                 
}                                                                                     

cc.defrost()
cc.detach()
```

**Another hint**: Use **javap** tool from JDK to disassemble compiled class before your modification and compare with byte code you have generated. It's easier to find bugs this way. You can also find byte code instructions you want to modify that way.